# How to get the CodeRequirement of an app using codesign?

Tags: macos, codesign

I'm reading Apple's Configuration Profile Reference, https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf, and on page 65 it is stated that the `CodeRequirement` identity dictionary key should be a string obtained via the command `codesign -display -r -`:

[image]

However, I'm not able to pass these options to my `codesign` command-line app. `codesign -d` works, but just returns the path of the executable:

```
/Applications> codesign -d Slack.app
Executable=/Applications/Slack.app/Contents/MacOS/Slack
```

However, `codesign -d -r` doesn't work:

```
/Applications> codesign -d -r Slack.app
Usage: codesign -s identity [-fv*] [-o flags] [-r reqs] [-i ident] path ... # sign
       codesign -v [-v*] [-R=<req string>|-R <req file path>] path|[+]pid ... # verify
       codesign -d [options] path ... # display contents
       codesign -h pid ... # display hosting paths
```

How do I get the `CodeRequirement` for an app using the `codesign` command-line tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out a dash was missing:

```
> codesign -d -r - /Applications/Slack.app
Executable=/Applications/Slack.app/Contents/MacOS/Slack
designated => identifier "com.tinyspeck.slackmacgap" and anchor apple generic and certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.6] /* exists */ and certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.13] /* exists */ and certificate leaf[subject.OU] = BQR82RBBHL
```